# Smallest and largest palindromes

Tags: performance, rust

I am new to rust and this is a program that finds out the palindromes between a range. All tests have been passed but this program is really slow in finding the 4 digits Palindromes.

This is an exercism exercise and Palindrome struct and struct methods new, value, and insert must be used in the final solution.

I need your help to review this code.

```
use std::cmp::Ordering;

#[macro_use]
extern crate itertools;

#[derive(Debug, Eq)]
pub struct Palindrome {
    factors: (u64, u64)

}


impl PartialOrd for Palindrome {
    fn partial_cmp(&self, other: &Self) -> Option<Ordering> {
        Some(self.cmp(other))
    }
}

impl Ord for Palindrome {
    fn cmp(&self, other: &Self) -> Ordering {
        // self.height.cmp(&other.height)
        (self.value()).cmp(&other.value()) 

    }
}


impl PartialEq for Palindrome {
    fn eq(&self, other: &Self) -> bool {
        // self.height == other.height
        self.value() == other.value() 


    }
}

impl Palindrome {
    pub fn new(a: u64, b: u64) -> Palindrome {
        Palindrome{
            factors: (b, a)
        }


    }

    pub fn value(&self) ->  u64 {
        self.factors.0*self.factors.1
    }

    pub fn insert(&mut self, a: u64, b: u64) {
            self.factors.0 = a;
            self.factors.1 = b;

    }
}


fn reverse_number(mut n: u64) -> u64{
    let radix = 10;
    let mut reversed = 0;

    while n != 0 {
        reversed = reversed * radix + n % radix;
        n /= radix;
    }

    reversed

}


fn is_palindrome(palindrome: &Palindrome) -> bool{
    if palindrome.value() == reverse_number(palindrome.value()){
        return true;
    }
    false
}

pub fn palindrome_products(min: u64, max: u64)-> Option<(Palindrome, Palindrome)>{
    if max <= min {
        return None;
    }

    let products = iproduct!(min..=max, min..=max)
        .map(|(i, j)| Palindrome::new(i, j))
        .filter(|palindrome| is_palindrome(palindrome));

        Some((products.clone().min()?, products.clone().max()?))


    }
```

Here is the full the test Suit

````
//! This test suite was generated by the rust exercise tool, which can be found at
//! https://github.com/exercism/rust/tree/master/util/exercise

use palindrome_products::{palindrome_products, Palindrome};

/// Process a single test case for the property `smallest`
///
/// All cases for the `smallest` property are implemented
/// in terms of this function.
fn process_smallest_case(input: (u64, u64), expected: Option<Palindrome>) {
    let min = palindrome_products(input.0, input.1).map(|(min, _)| min);
    assert_eq!(min, expected);
}

/// Process a single test case for the property `largest`
///
/// All cases for the `largest` property are implemented
/// in terms of this function.
/// 
fn process_largest_case(input: (u64, u64), expected: Option<Palindrome>) {
    let max = palindrome_products(input.0, input.1).map(|(_, max)| max);
    assert_eq!(max, expected);
}

#[test]
/// finds the smallest palindrome from single digit factors
fn test_finds_the_smallest_palindrome_from_single_digit_factors() {
    process_smallest_case((1, 9), Some(Palindrome::new(1, 1)));
}

#[test]
#[ignore]
/// finds the largest palindrome from single digit factors
fn test_finds_the_largest_palindrome_from_single_digit_factors() {
    let mut expect = Palindrome::new(1, 9);
    expect.insert(3, 3);
    process_largest_case((1, 9), Some(expect));
}

#[test]
#[ignore]
/// find the smallest palindrome from double digit factors
fn test_find_the_smallest_palindrome_from_double_digit_factors() {
    process_smallest_case((10, 99), Some(Palindrome::new(11, 11)));
}

#[test]
#[ignore]
/// find the largest palindrome from double digit factors
fn test_find_the_largest_palindrome_from_double_digit_factors() {
    process_largest_case((10, 99), Some(Palindrome::new(91, 99)));
}

#[test]
#[ignore]
/// find smallest palindrome from triple digit factors
fn test_find_smallest_palindrome_from_triple_digit_factors() {
    process_smallest_case((100, 999), Some(Palindrome::new(101, 101)));
}

#[test]
#[ignore]
/// find the largest palindrome from triple digit factors
fn test_find_the_largest_palindrome_from_triple_digit_factors() {
    process_largest_case((100, 999), Some(Palindrome::new(913, 993)));
}

#[test]
#[ignore]
/// find smallest palindrome from four digit factors
fn test_find_smallest_palindrome_from_four_digit_factors() {
    process_smallest_case((1000, 9999), Some(Palindrome::new(1001, 1001)));
}

#[test]
#[ignore]
/// find the largest palindrome from four digit factors
fn test_find_the_largest_palindrome_from_four_digit_factors() {
    process_largest_case((1000, 9999), Some(Palindrome::new(9901, 9999)));
}

#[test]
#[ignore]
/// empty result for smallest if no palindrome in the range
fn test_empty_result_for_smallest_if_no_palindrome_in_the_range() {
    process_smallest_case((1002, 1003), None);
}

#[test]
#[ignore]
/// empty result for largest if no palindrome in the range
fn test_empty_result_for_largest_if_no_palindrome_in_the_range() {
    process_largest_case((15, 15), None);
}

#[test]
#[ignore]
/// error result for smallest if min is more than max
fn test_error_result_for_smallest_if_min_is_more_than_max() {
    process_smallest_case((10000, 1), None);
}

#[test]
#[ignore]
/// error result for largest if min is more than max
fn test_error_result_for_largest_if_min_is_more_than_max() {
    process_largest_case((2, 1), None);
}


```
````

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Run `rustfmt`

You have some inconsistent formatting. Just run `cargo fmt` and your code will be automatically formatted to best practices.

## Make `Palindrome` a tuple struct

Instead of

```
#[derive(Debug, Eq)]
pub struct Palindrome {
    factors: (u64, u64),
}
```

Use

```
#[derive(Debug, Eq)]
pub struct Palindrome(u64, u64);
```

## Derive `PartialOrd`

Instead of

```
impl PartialOrd for Palindrome {
    fn partial_cmp(&self, other: &Self) -> Option<Ordering> {
        Some(self.cmp(other))
    }
}
```

Just use `#[derive(Debug, Eq, PartialOrd)]` instead, like what you already do for `Eq`.

## Rename `Palindrome`

It should be called something like `Pair` instead, unless required by your course—an instance of a `Palindrome` can actually not be a palindrome.

## Don't explicitly return

```rust
fn is_palindrome(palindrome: &Palindrome) -> bool {
    if palindrome.value() == reverse_number(palindrome.value()) {
        return true;
    }
    false
}
```

You're comparing a boolean, then returning based on that. Just return the boolean directly:

```rust
fn is_palindrome(palindrome: &Palindrome) -> bool {
    palindrome.value() == reverse_number(palindrome.value())
}
```

However, that function should probably be a method of `Palindrome` unless it's required to be separate by the course.

## Accept a range instead of `(min, max)`

Instead of

```
pub fn palindrome_products(min: u64, max: u64) -> Option<(Palindrome, Palindrome)> {
    if max <= min {
        return None;
    }

    let products = iproduct!(min..=max, min..=max)
        .map(|(i, j)| Palindrome::new(i, j))
        .filter(|palindrome| palindrome.is_palindrome());

    Some((products.clone().min()?, products.clone().max()?))
}

fn process_smallest_case(input: (u64, u64), expected: Option<Palindrome>) {
    let min = palindrome_products(input.0, input.1).map(|(min, _)| min);
    assert_eq!(min, expected);
}
```

How about

```
pub fn palindrome_products(range: RangeInclusive<u64>) -> Option<(Palindrome, Palindrome)> {
    let products = iproduct!(range.clone(), range)
        .map(|(i, j)| Palindrome::new(i, j))
        .filter(|palindrome| palindrome.is_palindrome());

    Some((products.clone().min()?, products.clone().max()?))
}

fn process_smallest_case(input: RangeInclusive<u64>, expected: Option<Palindrome>) {
    let min = palindrome_products(input).map(|(min, _)| min);
    assert_eq!(min, expected);
}
```

## Performance: use `Itertools::minmax`

Currently, you check if every number is a palindrome twice:

```rust
pub fn palindrome_products(range: RangeInclusive<u64>) -> Option<(Palindrome, Palindrome)> {
    let products = iproduct!(range.clone(), range)
        .map(|(i, j)| Palindrome::new(i, j))
        .filter(|palindrome| palindrome.is_palindrome());

    Some((products.clone().min()?, products.clone().max()?))
}
```

Instead, use:

```
pub fn palindrome_products(range: RangeInclusive<u64>) -> Option<(Palindrome, Palindrome)> {
    let products = iproduct!(range.clone(), range)
        .map(|(i, j)| Palindrome::new(i, j))
        .filter(|palindrome| palindrome.is_palindrome());
    match products.minmax() {
        MinMaxResult::NoElements => None,
        // You'll need to #[derive(Copy, Clone)] on Palindrome
        MinMaxResult::OneElement(p) => Some((p, p)),
        MinMaxResult::MinMax(min, max) => Some((min, max)),
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you could return a `impl Iterator<Item = Palindrome>` from `palindrome_products` and call `.min()` or `.max()` from `process_smallest_case` and `process_largest_case` respectively.

## Embed tests

Put your tests in the same file, then gate them behind a

```
#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    // tests
}
```

## Add benchmarks

I don't know how you're testing speed, but Rust doesn't optimize your code by default when running tests. Either use the [unstable `#[bench]` attribute](https://doc.rust-lang.org/unstable-book/library-features/test.html) or my personal favorite [Criterion](https://bheisler.github.io/criterion.rs/book/getting_started.html). Both will automatically compile for optimization.

## Final code

```
use std::cmp::Ordering;
use std::ops::RangeInclusive;

use itertools::iproduct;
use itertools::{Itertools, MinMaxResult};

#[derive(Copy, Clone, Debug, Eq, PartialOrd)]
pub struct Pair(u64, u64);

impl Ord for Pair {
    fn cmp(&self, other: &Self) -> Ordering {
        self.value().cmp(&other.value())
    }
}

impl PartialEq for Pair {
    fn eq(&self, other: &Self) -> bool {
        self.value() == other.value()
    }
}

impl Pair {
    pub fn new(a: u64, b: u64) -> Pair {
        Pair(b, a)
    }

    pub fn value(&self) -> u64 {
        self.0 * self.1
    }

    pub fn insert(&mut self, a: u64, b: u64) {
        self.0 = a;
        self.1 = b;
    }

    pub fn is_palindrome(&self) -> bool {
        self.value() == reverse_number(self.value())
    }
}

fn reverse_number(mut n: u64) -> u64 {
    let radix = 10;
    let mut reversed = 0;

    while n != 0 {
        reversed = reversed * radix + n % radix;
        n /= radix;
    }

    reversed
}

pub fn palindrome_products(range: RangeInclusive<u64>) -> Option<(Pair, Pair)> {
    let products = iproduct!(range.clone(), range)
        .map(|(i, j)| Pair::new(i, j))
        .filter(Pair::is_palindrome);
    match products.minmax() {
        MinMaxResult::NoElements => None,
        MinMaxResult::OneElement(p) => Some((p, p)),
        MinMaxResult::MinMax(min, max) => Some((min, max)),
    }
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use std::ops::RangeInclusive;

    use super::{palindrome_products, Pair};

    fn process_smallest_case(input: RangeInclusive<u64>, expected: Option<Pair>) {
        let min = palindrome_products(input).map(|(min, _)| min);
        assert_eq!(min, expected);
    }

    /// Process a single test case for the property `largest`
    ///
    /// All cases for the `largest` property are implemented in terms of this function.
    ///
    fn process_largest_case(input: RangeInclusive<u64>, expected: Option<Pair>) {
        let max = palindrome_products(input).map(|(_, max)| max);
        assert_eq!(max, expected);
    }

    #[test]
    /// finds the smallest palindrome from single digit factors
    fn test_finds_the_smallest_palindrome_from_single_digit_factors() {
        process_smallest_case(1..=9, Some(Pair::new(1, 1)));
    }

    #[test]
    #[ignore]
    /// finds the largest palindrome from single digit factors
    fn test_finds_the_largest_palindrome_from_single_digit_factors() {
        let mut expect = Pair::new(1, 9);
        expect.insert(3, 3);
        process_largest_case(1..=9, Some(expect));
    }

    #[test]
    #[ignore]
    /// find the smallest palindrome from double digit factors
    fn test_find_the_smallest_palindrome_from_double_digit_factors() {
        process_smallest_case(10..=99, Some(Pair::new(11, 11)));
    }

    #[test]
    #[ignore]
    /// find the largest palindrome from double digit factors
    fn test_find_the_largest_palindrome_from_double_digit_factors() {
        process_largest_case(10..=99, Some(Pair::new(91, 99)));
    }

    #[test]
    #[ignore]
    /// find smallest palindrome from triple digit factors
    fn test_find_smallest_palindrome_from_triple_digit_factors() {
        process_smallest_case(100..=999, Some(Pair::new(101, 101)));
    }

    #[test]
    #[ignore]
    /// find the largest palindrome from triple digit factors
    fn test_find_the_largest_palindrome_from_triple_digit_factors() {
        process_largest_case(100..=999, Some(Pair::new(913, 993)));
    }

    #[test]
    #[ignore]
    /// find smallest palindrome from four digit factors
    fn test_find_smallest_palindrome_from_four_digit_factors() {
        process_smallest_case(1000..=9999, Some(Pair::new(1001, 1001)));
    }

    #[test]
    #[ignore]
    /// find the largest palindrome from four digit factors
    fn test_find_the_largest_palindrome_from_four_digit_factors() {
        process_largest_case(1000..=9999, Some(Pair::new(9901, 9999)));
    }

    #[test]
    #[ignore]
    /// empty result for smallest if no palindrome in the range
    fn test_empty_result_for_smallest_if_no_palindrome_in_the_range() {
        process_smallest_case(1002..=1003, None);
    }

    #[test]
    #[ignore]
    /// empty result for largest if no palindrome in the range
    fn test_empty_result_for_largest_if_no_palindrome_in_the_range() {
        process_largest_case(15..=15, None);
    }

    #[test]
    #[ignore]
    /// error result for smallest if min is more than max
    fn test_error_result_for_smallest_if_min_is_more_than_max() {
        process_smallest_case(10000..=1, None);
    }

    #[test]
    #[ignore]
    /// error result for largest if min is more than max
    fn test_error_result_for_largest_if_min_is_more_than_max() {
        process_largest_case(2..=1, None);
    }
}
```

Comment: Couldn't figure out where I am testing for palindrome twice?

Comment: ''' filter(|palindrome| palindrome.is_palindrome());''' should be '''.filter(palindrome.is_palindrome);'''

Comment: @GraphicalDot you were testing for palindromes twice because you were cloning the iterator and using it in `min` and `max`. Iterators are lazy, so they're evaluated when used—there's no temporary array created. So `min` would run through the entire iterator and find minimums, and `max` would run through it again (calling `is_palindrome` on every number a second time). As for `filter`, you can either use `filter(|palindrome| palindrome.is_palindrome())` or `filter(Pair::is_palindrome)`. `filter(palindrome.is_palindrome)` is not valid Rust (nor is it valid Java, JS, or C++, but it is in Go).